# Speeding up my Ruby code

Tags: ruby, performance

I created an algorithm for selecting users, which is running more slowly than I would like since it's being used on an endless scroll webpage.

I don't know enough about Ruby to identify ways in which the efficiency can be improved. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
def gen_users(list_length)
new_selection = []

# get all users
all_users = User.all

# shuffle them randomly
shuffled_users = all_users.shuffle

# cycle through all users randomly
shuffled_users.each do |user|
    # check user profile isn't already in current selection
    if !@users.include?(user)
    # check user profile exists
    if user.etkh_profile
        profile_completeness = user.etkh_profile.get_profile_completeness

        # check user profile meets minimum requirements        
        if profile_completeness >= MIN_PROFILE_COMPLETENESS && user.avatar? \
        && user.etkh_profile.background.length >= MIN_BACKGROUND_LENGTH

        # insert randomness and bias towards profiles with high completeness
        r = Random.new
        rand = r.rand(1..10)  # random integer between 1 and 10
        product = rand * profile_completeness

        # threshold is defined by the probability that a profile with min profile completeness
        # will be selected

        max_product = MIN_PROFILE_COMPLETENESS * 10
        threshold = (1 - PROBABILITY_MIN_PROFILE) * max_product

        if product >= threshold
            # add to total list
            @users << user

            # add to list of latest selection
            new_selection << user
        end
        end
    end
    end

    # exit loop if enough users have been found
    break if new_selection.length >= list_length
end

# return this selection
return new_selection
end
```

Comment: Questions like this belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com. See [the FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#im-confused-what-questions-are-on-topic-for-this-site) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Two things you are doing wrong are:

- `threshold` is constant. You should not calculate that every time in the loop.
- `Random.new` should be reused. That is what it is for. You should not be creating new instance each time in the loop.

My refactorization of your code (steenslag's improvement incorporated) would be like this:

```
THRESHOLD = (1 - PROBABILITY_MIN_PROFILE) * MIN_PROFILE_COMPLETENESS * 10
RANDOM_GENERATOR = Random.new

def gen_users(list_length)
  (User.all - @users)
  .select do |user|
    profile = user.etkh_profile and
    profile.background.length >= MIN_BACKGROUND_LENGTH and
    (completeness = profile.get_profile_completeness) >= MIN_PROFILE_COMPLETENESS and
    RANDOM_GENERATOR.rand(1..10) * completeness >= THRESHOLD
  end
  .select(&:avatar?)
  .sample(list_length)
  .tap{|a| @users.concat(a)}
end
```

Comment: `sample(list_length)` in stead of `shuffle.first(list_length)`?

Comment: I forgoet about it. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, this is almost unrecognisable...really shows that I'm a C/C++/C# programmer who is trying to use Ruby...
It works except for it throws an error if the user does not have an etkh_profile. Some sort of if user.etkh_profile needs to precede profile.background.length

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to say what specifically creates bad performance, it depends on number of users for example. Also:

1. `max_product` and `threshold` are constants, you don't need to calculate them every cycle.
2. Maybe `user.etkh_profile` is a slow method? You call it three times per cycle.
3. Also you don't need to store two local variables with a big amount of data (`all_users` and `shuffled_users`). Instead, you can do something like `shuffled_users = User.all.shuffle`.